# Prevent Chrome Developer Tools automatically becoming the front-most window when a breakpoint hits

Tags: macos, google-chrome-devtools

I have developer tools attached to a nodeJS app, and I'm actively working with multiple js files open in multiple editor windows. Very often the app will refresh and since developer tools reattaches, it brings the dev tools window to front. This stops me mid-typing and causes me to immediately type in dev tools directly.

Can I somehow prevent this "pop to front" behaviour from developer tools in chrome? It's really disruptive.